JSON deserialization results of object returns wrong values unless the property is accessed directly
This one is very odd and I struggled to even produce a title for the question that somewhat describes what happens. The problem occurs when calling an API (which I have also written) via the Javascript Fetch API, and then deserializing the results. The object that my API returns for this exact query (captured via ASP.NET's Swagger UI) is:
{
  "ppqDate": "2024-05-14T00:00:00",
  "anticipatedRetirementAge": 70,
  "createdOn": "2024-05-14T12:36:30.86"
}

I have redacted a lot of the data, the actual object is larger than this but these are relevant fields that will help me show you the problem. I retrieve this data using the following code:
    result = await fetch(url, {
        credentials: 'include'
    });
    var data = await result.json();
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.ppqDate);
    return data;

The result of console.log(data) command is:
{
    "ppqDate": false,
    "anticipatedRetirementAge": false,
    "createdOn": "2024-05-14T12:36:30.86",
}

And the result of console.log(data.ppqDate) is:
2024-05-14T00:00:00

What I completely do not understand is why are the ppqDate and anticipatedRetirementAge fields showing up as false when printing the whole object but show up as actual, correct values when accessed directly? If instead of result.json() I first use result.text() it shows the correct values for all the fields but then when inevitably deserializing the object for some reason it converts some of the values to false.
As mentioned above accessing the values directly works throughout the app but when I try to serialize the object again to pass it to another API it serializes the values in question as false instead of their actual values, which causes me issues.
Does anyone know what could this possibly be? It seems to pick fields at random. It works for the createdOn field for example and a number of other numeric and string fields that I have redacted to keep this readable.

You're probably using Chrome. Change console.log(data) to console.log(JSON.stringify(data)). The console is asynchronous and weird things happen.

Also note that a datetime string with no timezone is a landmine of errors waiting to happen: if you parse it naively into a JS date object it will assume that it is in the browser's local time, whereas your database is almost certainly returning UTC.

@Pointy you are right, though I am using Edge. When using JSON.stringify in console it does return the correct values for it. The problem I still have is that after returning the data from that function I assign it to an object variable. Then as part of another function I need to serialize that object variable again and send it to another API. I do that precisely as you described, with JSON.stringify, but the resulting JSON string has the incorrect values. Do you know how to avoid this?

I would say that you should stick to the string representation of dates with APIs.  The problem seems to be related to how JSON treats certain data types. Js should be attempting to convert the original date values from your API response to a format compatible with JSON. If the conversion fails (e.g., due to an unexpected format or missing information), JSON might assign false to those fields as a placeholder. If possible, consider modifying the response format to return the dates in a more JSON-friendly format.

@Anandhu that makes sense and I will fix that on the API side, but this problem also occurs in other types of data. For example, the anticipatedRetirementAge field is a number, but JSON still fails the conversion there.

It sounds like something is modifying the object between the time you fetch it and when you send it to the other API. Please update the post to show this flow.

@AssistantToTheRegionalManager Please share more relevant portions of your code. Mostly the API side and how you are doing this part -> Then as part of another function I need to serialize that object variable again and send it to another API. 

So I have managed to figure out what was causing a problem. I'll explain here and post a minimal reproducible example:
The problem had nothing to do with the serialization/deserialization and the date formats in the end. It was actually very trivial, it turned out that I was accidentally assigning to the object's properties later on in the code, instead of evaluating them. The reason why it threw me in the loop and took me so long to figure this out can be summarised in this example (just javascript, no API calls needed):
var object = {
    name: "nameBeforeChange"
}

console.log(object);
console.log(object.name);

object.name = "nameAfterChange";

From above I would expect that the console would print the following:
{
    "name": "nameBeforeChange"
}

nameBeforeChange

What it actually returns is:
{
    "name": "nameAfterChange"
}

nameBeforeChange

This confused me for a while until @Pointy pointed out that console.log is asynchronous in Javascript. I was printing the object's contents directly after declaring it, so I assumed that the problem must have occurred before the print line, while actually it was happening much further in the code. This threw me in a loop and made me miss a very trivial mistake.
Even knowing that console is asynchronous, it was still confusing to me as to why printing just one of the properties of the object was working instantly while printing the whole object seemed to wait until a pretty large portion of my code ran first. I have tried setting up a timeout and seeing how much I needed to delay the execution to get the print statement to catch up, as follows:
var object = {
    name: "nameBeforeChange"
}

console.log(object);
console.log(object.name);


setTimeout(() => {
    object.name = "nameAfterChange";
    console.log(object);
}, 2300)

I had to slow it down by an entire 2.3 seconds just to print this object. I tested a range of values and anything below 2.3 seconds resulted in nameAfterChange being printed in the first print statement.
I guess the main point is that I underestimated how slow printing objects is in the console.
